# Why is this happening? all NULL values not collapsing in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Desc of MyTable]

Im am running this query

```
SELECT COUNT(*), Clearing 
FROM  MyTable 
WHERE ClearingDoc = '' 
GROUP BY Clearing;
```

And I get the following result. The NULL Values are not collapsing. Why? Any possible explanation and possible solution.

Result:
[image: result of query]

Comment: Could you post the structure of the table?

Comment: @OscarMartinez Posted :)

Comment: I would double check if those are truly null values in both records, not just sg that look like null values...

Comment: @Shadow. Thanks for the suggestion. I ran the query in Terminal (Windows PowerShell) and got a better view of what was going on. TOAD kind of destroys the view.

Comment: @Shadow `Clearing` is a `DATE`, not `VARCHAR`, so how could it look like null?

Comment: @Shadow cant a DATE have a NULL value?

Comment: Yes, but a non-null date shouldn't be displayed as `{null}`. But it looks like TOAD does this with zero dates.

Answer (score 0):

I ran the query in terminal (last time it was on TOAD) it gave a better picture.

[image: output]

Comment: Is this supposed to be the solution? If not, you should add it to the question.

Comment: If that's not the result you want, you could use `GROUP BY IFNULL(Clearing, DATE('0000-00-00'))`. Then it will merge all the null dates with the zero dates.

Comment: Beef this post up explaining what tools you used to get the original and the above output because this may be useful for other toad users.